# How much energy do photons lose when they hit a material that reflects that wavelength?

Tags: electricity, photons, photoelectric-effect

since germanium has the required energy of 0.72 eV. to brake an electron free, what if a photon has say, 100 eV? would the photon (if reflected by the germanium) lose only 0.72 eV each time it hits a germanium atom, or lose more eV?

Comment: An electron can get all of the energy. It will then lose energy to other electrons (assuming I stays in the solid).

Comment: i was wondering if a photon has around 10 eV and then germanium needs 0.72 eV so, could that single photon eject multiple electrons by having the photon reflected a couple times?

Comment: No. One electron will go in to an excited state and then thermaluze down to the conduction band,  making a lot more electron-hole pairs in the process.

Comment: Thanks so much i was working on a project and i could not find this answer to finish it off. ^.^ thx m8

Answer (score 0):

This is really two questions. The title

> How much energy do photons lose when they hit a material that reflects that wavelength?

is a different problem than in the question.

Reflection means that photons elastically scatter in the center of mass system of the "material +photon". In the lab frame, the mass of the material is so large that the [relativistic Doppler effect](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/reldop2.html) is very small, so the small loss of energy of the photon in the lab is not measureable.

The question in the body

> since germanium has the required energy of 0.72 eV. to brake an electron free, what if a photon has say, 100 eV? would the photon (if reflected by the germanium) lose only 0.72 eV each time it hits a germanium atom, or lose more eV?

Is about the [photoelectric effect](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html). *Reflection means elastic scattering* by definition, therefore if the photoelectric effect happens there is no reflection. The total energy of the photon scatters off an electron and releases it to interact further or to leave the surface of the material. [Compton scattering](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/comptint.html) may also happen, and a photon may lose part of its energy to the ejected electron, but it is not a reflection.